# Why is IntelliJ IDEA showing all packages separately?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

Example:

[image: Example]

I was working on some code, then I uploaded it to GitHub and afterward something popped up and I just clicked yes. I know I should have read it, but I was in a hurry, and now every project in IntelliJ IDEA shows up like this.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flatten packages option, in the project view config

[image]